# Mysqli query returns an unknown extra records with the actual result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm querying records it is fetching but it is showing an strange `empty record` which is unusual not even there in the database.

Extra record means an extra empty `<li>` in the list.
$dba is the database connection.

```
$dba=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','store');
```

`foreach` is not working properly.

Please help to solve.

```
<?php include ('inc/db.php');
$zmcats     = "select i.ename as iname,c.ename as cname, c.id as cid
from items i
inner join categories c on c.id = i.cat_id
where i.view > 4
and c.id = i.cat_id
and c.status = 1
group by c.id
";
$zmcat      = $dba->query($zmcats);
//$zzmcat       = array();
while ($zzmcat[] = $zmcat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){}
foreach ($zzmcat as $zcatzn) {
?>
<li class="category-list list-parent"><a href="#"><?php echo $zcatzn["cname"]; ?></a>
    <ul class="list-child">
    <?php
    $q  = "SELECT id, ename FROM items 
    WHERE view > 4 and status = 1 and cat_id='".$zcatzn['cid']."' ";
    $qq = $dba->query($q);
    while ($product = $qq->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
        <li class="category-list"><a href="#">
        <?php echo $product['ename']; ?>
        </a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Comment: So much missing information. Example db structure and data, what does this "extra record" look like? what is $dba? what does the query function look like? Which query is performing incorrectly?

Comment: Loose the foreach loop and just use the while loop but without the `[]`

Comment: I would also hazzard a guess that the data you get from the second query is already there in the results of the first query

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes but with the first query it shows each item with the same multiple times like 6 items and it will show 6 times that category name. this is the problem if u can solve that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i did the same and that worked already but why it doesnt work with foreach??

Comment: That sounds like a different question

Comment: @RiggsFolly yup kinda can u please do the same with the first query only so i will remove the 2nd one. with the first i took only the category name and with the second i took the items. please tell so i will make the other question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171105/discussion-between-fahad-almehaini-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: You will have to show an example of the result set you are getting

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u come to the chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach loop after the while loop is unnecessary, just use a simple while loop

```
$zmcats = "select i.ename as iname,c.ename as cname, c.id as cid
            from items i
                inner join categories c on c.id = i.cat_id
            where i.view > 4
            and c.id = i.cat_id
            and c.status = 1
            group by c.id";

$zmcat = $dba->query($zmcats);

while ($zzmcat = $zmcat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

?>
    <li class="category-list list-parent"><a href="#"><?php echo $zcatzn["cname"]; ?></a>
    <ul class="list-child">
<?php
    $q  = "SELECT id, ename 
            FROM items 
            WHERE view > 4 
            and status = 1 
            and cat_id='$zcatzn[cid]'";

    $qq = $dba->query($q);
    while ($product = $qq->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>
        <li class="category-list"><a href="#">
<?php 
        echo $product['ename']; 
?>
        </a></li>
<?php 
    } 
?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php 
} 
?>
```